# The blog needs help

Tags: discussion

The blog needs help...*seriously*.

I've got an interview I've been slowly trying to piece together, but beyond that (eventually) nothing... **we need contributors**.  As a community, we need some members to step forward and have a go at making a blog entry.  Drop me a line in here as an answer or contact me in chat but we need your help!

Comment: I'll try to get some time to contribute in the next week.

Comment: As soon as my deck is done, I'll contribute. I'm running out of time before winter, so it has to be done, but once it is, I'll start working on some of the Lightroom blogs.

Answer (score 8):

What if we try to build a repository of prompts? Topics/themes to inspire people and give them concrete ideas to work with. For example, I think it might be cool to have the creator of the weekly featured image do a short post explaining what inspired the shot and/or how s/he achieved the effect in the shot. It's easy, it's relevant to the site, and there will always be material for it. (This would, of course, require that the weekly featured image winners be willing to do that, but I think it would be a neat series. Even as an occasional thing - once every three or four weeks, since I'm sure not everyone will want to write.)

And just to keep in mind: blog posts don't have to be long. A couple paragraphs is plenty. It doesn't have to be a burdensome task that will take weeks to complete. :)

Comment: Weekly featured image idea is excellent.

Comment: So, should we start a thread for *specific* topics as a blog idea repo?

Comment: Yes! One idea per answer, so we can get a sense of what people would want to both read and write?

Comment: Done and done. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm happy to write more articles, if you can give me some topics.

Comment: I'd love to see a write up of your experience doing your first wedding gig or such.

Comment: That's a good idea. You mean the second-shooting gig?

Comment: Yup, thats what i mean